# In layman's terms, how should I use appdelegate file in buliding an iOS app?

Tags: ios, appdelegate

It seems there is no good definitive and useful explanation on this other than extensive, jargon-filled ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layman's terms, the app delegate file is best used for catching (and then doing something in response to) important app related events, like:

```
application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
applicationDidBecomeActive:
applicationDidEnterBackground:
applicationWillResignActive: (Called when leaving the foreground state.)
applicationWillEnterForeground: (Called when transitioning out of the background state.)
applicationWillTerminate:
```

You can have your app do whatever it needs to do whenever iOS tells your app these things are happening.  For example, do you need to save a current game state when the phone is getting an incoming call, that's where you implement your own `applicationWillResignActive` method.

Other developers will also sometimes put code that doesn't easily fit into subclassed view controllers into the app delegate file, but as you improve your iOS programming skills you'll find there's plenty of other places (and other ways) to save & handle non UI related functions.

Comment: Good answer. (voted)

Answer (score 1):

Layman terms: App delegate is nothing but a file that contains functions to manage the application.

**Most simple and common use of this file is to manage various application states** For example, if after launching the application, you want might wanna ask user if they want to opt for receiving notifications. Then you implement `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function. In this function, you can implement registration for notification.

Another example method is `applicationDidEnterBackground`. As the name implies, you can do some task right after the application enters background. It is probably the most useful class, where "**states**" of your app are managed (active, background, forground, launching etc.)